# Can I write text to file in rootBundle？

Tags: flutter, dart

I can load text in rootBundle:

```dart
final _path = 'assets/markdown/markdown_demo.md';
final content = await rootBundle.loadString(_path);
```

But how can I write text to file in rootBundle?

I use `File` but it throw error:

```dart
final file = File(_path);
file.writeAsString(_textEditingController.text);
```

Error:

> Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/markdown/markdown_demo.md' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)